# How to remember user's detail to avoid asking him to sign in everytime in JavaFx Desktop Application

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, javafx, desktop-application

I am trying to build an application that requires users to log in. When they register I store their information in the MySQL database. (For now, I am just using localhost) I don't want users to write their login details every time they open up the application. How can I avoid this? I am totally clueless. I will be very thankful if someone helps.

Comment: You will probably need a cache, with a token system.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 2):

You can persist data to user's local profile via [java.util.prefs.Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html). You should probably avoid saving sensitive data but 'username' is fair game.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Hollis Waite, you can use the java.util.prefs library.

```
import java.util.prefs.*;
```

Make a Remember Me checkbox and put it on your login scene:

```
@FXML 
private CheckBox rememberMeCheckBox;
```

Then you can use the action event from the checkbox to save the username. Again, as pointed out by Hellis, stick with saving the username and never handle naked passwords.

Example:

```
@FXML
void handleRememberUser(ActionEvent event) {
    if(rememberMeCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        // Let's validate the username field isn't empty (Optional)
        if(!usernameField.getText().isEmpty()){
            Preferences pref = Preferences.userRoot();
            String userName = usernameField.getText();
            pref.put("username", userName);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will probably want the username field to automatically fill the username in memory, right?

In that case you have to make your LoginController implement the initializable class, to have access to the "initialize" method, which can run methods when the class is initialized.

Example:

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable{
    /// Your whole code in here
}
```

Then all you have left to do is override the method initialize (Intellij = Alt + Insert/ Override and choose initialize().

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
       
        usernameField.setText(Preferences.userRoot().get("username", "Username")); // gets the username form the preferences, if userRoot not set, returns "Username"
    }
```

Complete code example would look like:

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorRoot;


    @FXML
    private TextField usernameField;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox rememberMeCheckbox;


    @FXML
void handleRememberUser(ActionEvent event) {
    if(rememberMeCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        // Let's validate the username field isn't empty (Optional)
        if(!usernameField.getText().isEmpty()){
            Preferences pref = Preferences.userRoot();
            String userName = usernameField.getText();
            pref.put("email", userName);
        }
    }
}

    @FXML
    void handleLogin(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        validateUser();
    }

    @FXML
    void handleEnterPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        validateUser();
    }


    private void validateUser() {


        if (usernameField.getText().isEmpty() || passwordField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            // Tell the user fields cannot be empty
        } else {
            // Connect to DB
            DatabaseConnection connectNow = new DatabaseConnection();
            Connection connectDB = connectNow.getConnection();


            String query = "SELECT etc etc etc";

            try {

                Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

                if (rs.next()) {
                    // Validate your user however you are doing it
            
                } else {
                    // User not found, do something
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getCause();
            }
        }
    }

    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Will set usernameField to whatever was stored in userRoot.
        usernameField.setText(Preferences.userRoot().get("email", "User email"));
    }
}
```

Side note, if you are making a login and want to compare passwords, please start using encryption libraries. Never handle naked Strings for passwords.

springframeword.security.crypto is a good library.

Voila.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the sensitive data in the keyring of the platform.

The [NetBeans Platform](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/) (Swing based Rich Client Platform) for example provides a Java based [Keyring API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-keyring/org/netbeans/api/keyring/package-summary.html).
There seems to be also a [port](https://github.com/joval/jKeyring) independent from the NetBeans Platform.